# How to copy Log4J output to a string?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am using IntelliJ and Java.
I want to copy the output of the running program to a string.
This solution must work both locally in IntelliJ and in a Jenkins job.

For example, my running console output looks like this:

```
log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.stdot

log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "stdot". log4j:ERROR

Could not find value for key log4j.appender.stdout log4j:ERROR Could
not instantiate appender named "stdout". [1;34m2019-05-12 08:17:38
Property file env/application.properties parsed successfully[0m
```

I want to copy all of this log to a string.
I've tried numerous solutions but none of them have worked.

Comment: there are settings to (also) save the `log4j` output to file

Answer (score 1):

You could use [System.setOut()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut-java.io.PrintStream-) with a [StringWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/StringWriter.html).

For example:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
System.setOut(new PrintStream(stream));
String output = stream.toString();
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8708357/6288436) for a solution that doesn't redirect System.out. This is also the first result that comes up on Google, and I'm sure you got suggested that thread when you made this question.

Comment: A. I didn't read that suggestion...thanks for the code, but it doesn't work...

Comment: Does it throw an exception or is the string just empty? The method printing the error might not be using `System.out`, try `System.setErr()`.

Comment: The code fails compilation...I attached an image (Can't you see it?)

Comment: Ah, my bad. I forgot `setOut` doesn't use Writer classes. See my edit. It's basically a simplified version of the linked thread.

Comment: Sorry, it compiles but returns an empty string now

Comment: Log4J probably uses some other output stream then. From what I can see it's more complicated than just capturing `System.out` or `System.err`. I don't use Log4J so I wouldn't know how to do this personally, but [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043566/capture-log4j-output) the best help I can give you.

Comment: I found out the solution...if any one wants to use...                                    

 private java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream out;                                                                   
 out = new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream();
 System.setOut(new java.io.PrintStream(out));                                                        
 out.toString();